# Can't update or download apps without WiFi

Tags: google-play-store, oneplus-3, oxygenos

I have a OnePlus 3T Oxygen 4.1.7. I can no longer download/update apps on the Play Store without WiFi, I used to be able to until I accidentally checked to always download over WiFi only.

Here are the things I tried to fix it.

- I've already changed: Play Store > Settings > Auto-update apps to Auto-update apps at any time. Data charges may apply.
- I've also changed Settings > Google > Data Management > Update Drive-enabled app files - Over wifi or cellular.
- I've uninstalled the Play Store and then reinstalled it as well.
- I've restarted multiple times after each of the above steps.

So far nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem where I was unable to download any system updates or apps, apps from Google Play Store without WiFi. Even the apps from MI app could not be downloaded. I found out that I had restricted data usage on the Downloads app from both the SIM cards.

Go to Settings> Apps> manage apps> Downloads> Restrict data usage. Check both data services.

Answer (score 1):

Clear Data these apps:

- Google Play Store
- Google Play Services
- Settings

One of these apps may contain the data that prevents your device to have additional charges. But I'm not really sure if this will work.

The very best solution I know is to factory reset your device to clear all the settings you entered therein.

Comment: I also have faced this issue when my phone did format and I found solution as follows: Settings - Manage Apps (this is my phone. It may vary displaying name like apps, app settings, etc.) - Google Play Services - Clear Data... and then.. Google Play Store - Clear Data.. After clearing data from both it's okay to use as I like to...

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update or download any app and selected the setting auto-update over WiFi, then you need to go to the My apps and Update buttons where you will see many apps are queued for the update. You need to cancel the downloading by clicking on the cross sign, after that you will see an update button next to the app. Now, your app is ready for update without any WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, the location of this setting changed.

Open Google Play.

- Tap on your profile picture (on the upper right hand corner).
- Tap on **Settings** > **Network preferences** > **App download preference**
- Then, select **Over any network** and then tap **Done**.